# SQL Query to determine which rows can be consolidated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have customers that are registering for an event.  There are 2 types of registrations "Basic Package" and "Full Package".  The basic package includes only the person registering. Each additional guest is an additional charge.  The full package includes 2 adults (one being the person registering) and 2 children.  Then each additional guest is an additional charge.  Each customer can add as many basic and full registrations as they wish.

My task is to write a query that will evaluate all registrations for each customer and return the customer's ID if they have any registrations that can be combined to lower their total cost. We have two tables to maintain this data - one for each registration and a second table for each registration's additional guests.  Please see the [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5Fv7Yb8rff31uH6YJCi68/4) example of how the data is structured.

In the example data, there are 3 customers '00001', '00002', and '00003'.  For the example data, my query should return the customer Id's for '00001' and '00002' but not '00003'.

Customer '00001' has 3 registrations (one basic and two fulls).  The 1st full registration for Jim Smith already contains 2 adults and 2 children.  However, the 2nd full registration (Pam Jones) only has 1 adult and 2 children.  Therefore, the basic registration for John Doe is not necessary since John Doe can be added as the 2nd adult for Pam Jone's registration.

Customer '00002' has two full registrations for Walter Mann and Paula Wilson.  Walter's registration contains the two adults and two children that come with the package. But also includes an additional adult and additional child - each of which are an additional charge.  However, Paula Wilson's registration only includes one adult and one child.  So, Walter's additional adult and additional child can be moved to Paula's registration. *NOTE - my data doesn't reflect this. But if Walter's registrations contains more additional adults and/or children than what Paula's registration can accommodate, it will still be flagged since it would still lower customer '00002's total cost by filling as many available open slots as possible.

Customer '00003' has two registrations - one basic and one full.  The basic registration for Albert Palmer includes an extra adult and extra child at additional charges.  However, the second registration for Dalton Evans already contains two adults and two children and therefore, can not reduce the overall cost for the customer.

So, as stated before, I need a query to evaluate all registrations for all customers and return the customer Id's if any of their registrations can be optimized.  This level of SQL is over my head. So, any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. For the sake of making this a little more understandable, I'm going to use a temporary table to illustrate a possible solution. If it works for you and you don't want the table there, you should be able to collapse the query a bit. Here's what I want to know about each reservation:

```
declare @RegistrationDetail table
(
    RegistrationId int,
    CustomerId varchar(5),
    AdultsIncluded int,
    ChildrenIncluded int,
    AdultsRemaining int,
    ChildrenRemaining int
);
```

The first two fields are going to come straight from your `dbo.Registrations` table. `AdultsIncluded` and `ChildrenIncluded` will give the total number of adults and children, respectively, that already appear on each reservation. `AdultsRemaining` and `ChildrenRemaining` will give the number of adults and children, respectively, that may still be added to that reservation without incurring an additional charge. So for a full registration, the remaining counts will be two minus the number of reservations already used, while for a basic reservation the remaining counts will always be zero.

```
with GuestCountCTE as
(
    select
        Reg.RegistrationId,
        AdultsIncluded = 1 + sum(case when Guest.GuestType in ('Adult Included', 'Additional Adult') then 1 else 0 end),
        ChildrenIncluded = sum(case when Guest.GuestType in ('Child Included', 'Additional Child') then 1 else 0 end)
    from
        dbo.Registrations Reg
        left join dbo.RegistrationAdditionalGuestDetails Guest on Reg.RegistrationId = Guest.RegistrationId
    group by
        Reg.RegistrationId
)
insert @RegistrationDetail
select
    Reg.RegistrationId,
    Reg.customerId,
    GCount.AdultsIncluded,
    GCount.ChildrenIncluded,
    AdultsRemaining = case when Reg.RegistrationType = 'Full' and GCount.AdultsIncluded < 2 then 2 - GCount.AdultsIncluded else 0 end,
    ChildrenRemaining = case when Reg.RegistrationType = 'Full' and GCount.ChildrenIncluded < 2 then 2 - GCount.ChildrenIncluded else 0 end
from
    dbo.Registrations Reg
    inner join GuestCountCTE GCount on Reg.RegistrationId = GCount.RegistrationId;
```

The CTE builds the numbers of reservations already used, and the `INSERT` statement that follows takes that data directly from the CTE and then infers the numbers of reservations remaining. A few things to note here:

1. You could certainly do this without a CTE. I've used one just to break the approach down a little further, and to avoid having to write the expressions for `AdultsIncluded` and `ChildrenIncluded` twice each.
2. I have assumed here that you would never have a full registration that has an "Additional Adult" without already having used its "Adult Included," or one that has an "Additional Child" without already having used both of its "Child Included"s. If that is not the case, then while the overall approach will still work, you'll need to be a little smarter about how you determine the available spaces left in each reservation.
3. Note the `1` added to the `AdultsIncluded` expression; that represents the adult who made the registration in the first place.

Here's the data I now have in `@RegistrationDetail`:

```
RegistrationId   CustomerId   AdultsIncluded   ChildrenIncluded   AdultsRemaining   ChildrenRemaining
1                00001        1                0                  0                 0
2                00001        2                2                  0                 0
3                00001        1                2                  1                 0
4                00002        3                3                  0                 0
5                00002        1                1                  1                 1
6                00003        2                1                  0                 0
7                00003        2                2                  0                 0
```

So now what I need are the identifiers of any customer that has at least one reservation where the numbers of adults and children who appear on that reservation are less than or equal to the total number of unused adult and child spaces on all of that customer's *other* reservations. This is actually not so hard:

```
with RemaindersByCustomerCTE as
(
    select
        Detail.CustomerId,
        AdultsRemaining = sum(Detail.AdultsRemaining),
        ChildrenRemaining = sum(Detail.ChildrenRemaining)
    from
        @RegistrationDetail Detail
    group by
        Detail.CustomerId
)
select
    Rem.CustomerId
from
    RemaindersByCustomerCTE Rem
where
    exists
    (
        select 1
        from
            @RegistrationDetail Detail
        where
            Detail.AdultsIncluded <= (Rem.AdultsRemaining - Detail.AdultsRemaining) and
            Detail.ChildrenIncluded <= (Rem.ChildrenRemaining - Detail.ChildrenRemaining)
    );
```

Here I have first used a CTE to produce a result set that has one record per customer along with the total numbers of unused adult and child spaces each customer has on *all* of their reservations. That CTE yields:

```
CustomerId   AdultsRemaining   ChildrenRemaining
00001        1                 0
00002        1                 1
00003        0                 0
```

And finally, the bit after the CTE uses a semi-join (i.e., the `EXISTS`) to return only the set of `CustomerId` values for which there is a registration that meets the criteria given above. Note especially the `WHERE` clause in this query: I can't simply write `Detail.AdultsIncluded <= Rem.AdultsRemaining` because `Rem.AdultsRemaining` is the number of adult spaces available on *all* of the customer's reservations, including the one represented by the `Detail` record, and the customer can't save money by moving guests from one registration into the empty spaces on that same registration. The final result set is:

```
CustomerId
00001
00002
```

Does this look like it'll work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  I modified it to fit my exact needs and it works perfectly.  Not sure why people are down voting my question.  But I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

At minimum you need a registration for each pair (or partial pair) of adults (children). If you have more registrations than those two numbers would demand, then they could be consolidated.

```
select r.customerid
from Registrations r left outer join RegistrationAdditionalGuestDetails g
    on g.registrationid = r.registrationid
group by r.customerid
having
    count(distinct r.registrationid) >
      ceiling(
        (
          count(distinct r.registrationid) /* non-guest adults */ +
          count(case when guesttype like '%Adult%' then 1 end)
        ) / 2.0
      )
    or
      ceiling(count(case when guesttype like '%Child%' then 1 end) / 2.0)
        between 1 and /* children are optional */
          count(distinct case when r.registrationtype = 'Full' then r.registrationid end);
```

Should the package definitions change it would be easy to tweak the calculation as necessary. Also I'm assuming that full registration for just two adults is better than two basics. If that's incorrect I'm still curious to learn more of the parameters of the desired consolidation rules.